# Matlab plot3 line color setting

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, rgb, figure

I want to plot a three-dimensional line chart using the *plot3* function in matlab.
The following code works to plot the lines with specified colour names 'r','g','k', etc.
However, it gives an error when I replace the first colour by 'myGreen' using the RGB triplet: '*Error using plot3
Vectors must be the same length.*'
How can I resolve this issue?

```
[xx,zz]=meshgrid(1:230,1:4);
x1=(xx(1,:));
x2=(xx(2,:));
x3=(xx(3,:));
x4=(xx(4,:));

z1=(zz(1,:));
z2=(zz(2,:));
z3=(zz(3,:));
z4=(zz(4,:));

yy=rand(230,4);
y1=(yy(:,1));
y2=(yy(:,2));
y3=(yy(:,3));
y4=(yy(:,4));

% custom colour 
myGreen=[0 0.5 0];
index={'data1','data2','data3','data4'}

figure
% It works and produces the attached figure
plot3(x1',z1',y1','r',x2',z2',y2','m', x3',z3',y3','b',x4',z4',y4','k')
% It doesn't work
plot3(x1',z1',y1','Color',myGreen,x2',z2',y2','m', x3',z3',y3','b',x4',z4',y4','k')

set(gca,'YTick',1:4,'YTickLabel',index)
grid on
xlabel('xlabel','FontSize',10);
zlabel('zlabel','FontSize',10)
axis tight
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [`plot3` documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html), the function accepts a number of syntaxes:

```
plot3(X,Y,Z)
plot3(X,Y,Z,LineSpec)
plot3(X1,Y1,Z1,...,Xn,Yn,Zn)
plot3(X1,Y1,Z1,LineSpec1,...,Xn,Yn,Zn,LineSpecn)
plot3(___,Name,Value)
etc...
```

The working line from the example:

```
plot3(x1',z1',y1','r',x2',z2',y2','m', x3',z3',y3','b',x4',z4',y4','k')
```

corresponds to the syntax

```
plot3(X1,Y1,Z1,LineSpec1,...,Xn,Yn,Zn,LineSpecn)
```

In the non-working line you've effectively substituted `LineSpec1` (`'r'`) with the `Name,Value` pair `'Color',myGreen`. But there is no syntax `plot3(X1,Y1,Z1,Name,Value,...,Xn,Yn,Zn,LineSpecn)`.

`Name,Value` pairs are only accepted at the end of the argument list and apply to all series. You can achieve what appears to be the intended behavior by splitting up the calls to `plot3` and using `hold` to keep them all on the same axes:

```
plot3(x1',z1',y1','Color',myGreen)
hold on
plot3(x2',z2',y2','m')
plot3(x3',z3',y3','b')
plot3(x4',z4',y4','k')
```

Answer (score 0):

Plot as you do now, save the handles, and then alter the color of the first one afterwards.

```matlab
h=plot3(x1',z1',y1','r',x2',z2',y2','m', x3',z3',y3','b',x4',z4',y4','k');
set(h(1),'Color',myGreen);
```